# Why doesn't this web crawler obey requests to stop crawling my pages?

Tags: web-crawlers, http-headers

I have a hidden page that verifies internal payments from PayPal. The page has the following in its HTTP headers:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
```

But once in a while I see this in the page logs:

```
HOST: 208-115-111-71-reverse.wowrack.com
USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Ezooms/1.0; ezooms.bot@gmail.com)
```

What is that `wowrack.com`? And how do I stop it crawling my pages?

Comment: You probably want to lock the page down a bit more than just robots.txt or robots meta tag if it's used for financial transactions. Both of those are not replacements for authentication.

Comment: @JohnMueller: No, obviously the page itself uses the internal login process to connect to PayPal, etc. and if it's loaded by a crawler it fails. I just don't want to run this authentication for nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that your directive in the `X-Robots-Tag` is for *indexation*, not *crawling*.

**[EDIT]** Explicit reference to this point is made here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag

> This document details how Google handles the page-level ***indexing*** settings allow you to control how Google makes content available through search results. You can specify these by including a meta tag on (X)HTML pages or in an HTTP header.

(emphasis mine)

**[/END EDIT]**

To prevent crawling of this page, you should consider blocking this specific page using an exclusion in your `robots.txt` file. More information here: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

If this doesn't work (as not all crawlers respect this file), then you can look at blocking by IP or domain.

Comment: In my opinion, if the crawler doesn't respect the `X-Robots-Tag`, the _robots.txt_ directive won't work either.

Comment: Not all crawlers are that sophisticated, but your point is valid that a brute-force block for some crawlers is the only alternative when they ignore directives.

Answer (score 2):

Several web crawlers don't respect the `X-Robots-Tag` in HTTP headers. I think this is the case for `wowrack.com`.

To block crawling of your page for this web crawler, you can use *[.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/htaccess.html)* (if you use Apache as a web server). Add these lines to block IP address in your *.htaccess* file:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 208.115.111.
allow from all
```

To be more aggressive, you can also block the hostname but it's not the better solution:

```
order allow,deny
deny from wowrack.com
allow from all
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, what is that wowrack.com?

Comment: It's a cloud hosting company. It looks like someone is running a spider script from one of their accounts. You might consider blocking an IP range instead (`deny from 208.115.111.`).

Comment: I wouldn't use `deny from <hostname>` directives.  They slow the server down ([reference](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4335019.htm)).   Instead, I would suggest denying based on user agent as described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env)

Comment: Would it help to contact them and ask them about such account? (Provided the company itself is legit.)

Comment: @MikeF You could contact their "abuse" department with a suggestion they look into it (include the IP address `208-115-111-71`), but just making requests is not really against any TOS, unless they're attempting to hack into your server.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm only seeing this in that reference: `Denying by IP is much less server intensive than denying by host.` Did you see the warning in the second link: `Access control by User-Agent is an unreliable technique, since the User-Agent header can be set to anything at all, at the whim of the end user.` There are quite a few security modules that would be more efficient, and blocking the unwanted/abusive IP's using a firewall is even more so, but adding an IP range to the config file is probably the easiest for the OP to do.

Comment: I agree with dan on this case, I didn't realize that Wowrack was a web hosting company. I don't think blocking user-agent can be useful on this case, especially if it's a running script. I have edited my answer.